# Non-blocking sockets not working on Nitrous.io

Tags: python, sockets, nitrousio

```
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect_ex(ip, 80)
sock.settimeout(30)
sock.setblocking(0)
sock.sendall(str.encode(
    "GET " + randstr + target.path + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + target.netloc + "\r\n" + str(
        cur_header) + "\r\n\r\n\r\n"))
data = sock.recv(1024)
print(data)
```

It seems, it works like blocking socket, because it returns data.
Does Nitrous.io support non-blocking sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Nitrous.io doesn't support non-blocking. It only support ports `1024 - 9999` now.

But you can running an app on `port 3000` to forward `port 80`, if you are behind the firewall.